# How do I stop Excel from converting numbers to date?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I save my DataFrame as csv and try to open it in excel, problem is that excel converts some of my float data to `date` format. I use excel 2016.

This is how my DataFrame looks like in excel.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to stop this ?

Comment: Not sure there's a way, other than stop using CSV.  https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/6/21355674/human-genes-rename-microsoft-excel-misreading-dates

Comment: Format the cells to general or number.

Comment: @SolarMike i did it but i get difrent values. When I will change excel will change to representative date values

Comment: @maciej.o may be you find this documentation from `Microsoft` useful --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8

Comment: Stop using Excel to open CSV's? Or, *import* the CSV into Excel, specifying the type for each column?

Comment: As @BigBen wrote, you should **IMPORT** the file into Excel, using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard. By doing so you can specify the column types, and avoid your problem.  And you can set things up so you only have to do this once, with the import process being re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the required column and then press CNT + 1 and then select the correct format. As you are saving the file as CSV, you have to repeat this action every time you open the file as CSV don't save such information and by default excel reads everything as generic format. You can find more details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Excel to open a CSV file it will attempt to interpret each cell. Something that resembles a date will be formatted as a date. Excel has the same behaviour if you type or paste something that resembles a date into a cell formatted as General.

However, if you paste the same data into a cell that has already been formatted other than General it will no longer be re-interpreted.

Format a blank Excel sheet as you expect the data to appear. Open the CSV file in a text editor such as Notepad. Copy the data then paste it into the Excel sheet.

If you aren't sure how the data should appear, for example because you aren't sure about the number of columns, you can format all of the cells as Text. That will suppress interpretation but you can change the formatting afterwards.

Incidentally, I discovered a bug in Excel that relates to this. When you add a new row to the bottom of a table it inherits the formatting of the row above, however Excel does this in the wrong order. To see this, format a table column as Text. In the row below the last row of the table, formatted General, type '1/1/2022'. Excel misinterprets this as 44562. That is because it interpreted 1/1/2022 as a date then changed the formatting to Text to match the row above.

Consequently, when applying the initial formatting you should select at least as many rows as in your CSV file. The easiest way to achieve this is simply to format entire columns.

In your particular case you probably want to pre-format certain columns as Number.

Comment: Thanks, I open my dataframe in online program and i copy it from there and paste to formated cell in excel .